# Selenium Python iterating over a table of rows is showing IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a HTML table with 4 rows and some columns.  I am iterating over the rows, column 4 to check if the value "87" is not there.

I am getting an list index out of range error.

I have inspected the HTML there is a table for the header (snippet below) and a table where the results are, main body (snippet below)

My Selenium Python method is:

```
def is_match_audit_code_displayed_for_the_filter_report_results(self, code):
    # Params code: match audit code e.g. 86
    try:
        table_id = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'reporting_view_report_dg_main_body')))        
        rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
        for row in rows:
            # Get the columns
            col_match_audit = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[4]  # This is the Match Audit column
            print "col_match_audit.text = "
            if (col_match_audit.text not in code):
                return True
        return False
    except NoSuchElementException, e:
        print "Element not found "
        print e
        self.save_screenshot("reports_match_filter_results_page_match_audit_code_element")
        return False
```

The full error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore 501 Regression Test\ClearCore 501 - Regression Test\TestCases\ReportingPage_TestCase_Regression.py", line 382, in test_B5_view_matches_filtered_report_crm_escr_crm2_match_filters_Do_Name_check_match_audit_code_is_displayed
    reports_view_results_page.is_match_audit_code_displayed_for_the_filter_report_results("86")
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore 501 Regression Test\ClearCore 501 - Regression Test\Pages\Reports\reports_view_results.py", line 143, in is_match_audit_code_displayed_for_the_filter_report_results
    col_match_audit = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[4]  # This is the Match Audit column
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The header is in separate table.  The HTML snippet for the header is:

```
<table id="reporting_view_report_dg_main_header" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
    <thead>
    <tr __gwt_header_row="0">
        <th class="GJPPK2LBPM GJPPK2LBNM" __gwt_header="header-gwt-uid-5566" __gwt_column="column-gwt-uid-5565"
            colspan="1"/>
        <th class="GJPPK2LBPM" __gwt_header="header-gwt-uid-5568" __gwt_column="column-gwt-uid-5567" colspan="1"/>
        <th class="GJPPK2LBPM" __gwt_header="header-gwt-uid-5570" __gwt_column="column-gwt-uid-5569" colspan="1">
<span class="" title=""
      style="display: block; position: relative ;font-family: arial; color: rgb(50,50,50); cursor: pointer;">
<span class=""
      style="display: block; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; empty-cells: show; padding-right: 1px;">
<span class="" title="" style="">USN</span>
</span>
<span style="display: block; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; position: absolute; width: 10px; cursor: col-resize;"/>
</span>
        </th>
        <th class="GJPPK2LBPM" __gwt_header="header-gwt-uid-5572" __gwt_column="column-gwt-uid-5571" colspan="1">
<span class="" title=""
      style="display: block; position: relative ;font-family: arial; color: rgb(50,50,50); cursor: pointer;">
<span class=""
      style="display: block; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; empty-cells: show; padding-right: 1px;">
<span class="" title="" style="">MATCH_AUDIT</span>
</span>
<span style="display: block; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; position: absolute; width: 10px; cursor: col-resize;"/>
</span>
        </th>
        <th class="GJPPK2LBPM" __gwt_header="header-gwt-uid-5574" __gwt_column="column-gwt-uid-5573" colspan="1">
<span class="" title=""
      style="display: block; position: relative ;font-family: arial; color: rgb(50,50,50); cursor: pointer;">
<span class=""
      style="display: block; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; empty-cells: show; padding-right: 1px;">
<span class="" title="" style="">DOB_SOURCE_FIELDS</span>
</span>
<span style="display: block; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; position: absolute; width: 10px; cursor: col-resize;"/>
</span>
        </th>
        <th class="GJPPK2LBPM" __gwt_header="header-gwt-uid-5576" __gwt_column="column-gwt-uid-5575" colspan="1">
        <th class="GJPPK2LBPM" __gwt_header="header-gwt-uid-5578" __gwt_column="column-gwt-uid-5577" colspan="1">
        <th class="GJPPK2LBPM" __gwt_header="header-gwt-uid-5580" __gwt_column="column-gwt-uid-5579" colspan="1">
        <th class="GJPPK2LBPM" __gwt_header="header-gwt-uid-5582" __gwt_column="column-gwt-uid-5581" colspan="1">
        <th class="GJPPK2LBPM" __gwt_header="header-gwt-uid-5584" __gwt_column="column-gwt-uid-5583" colspan="1">
        <th class="GJPPK2LBPM" __gwt_header="header-gwt-uid-5586" __gwt_column="column-gwt-uid-5585" colspan="1">
        <th class="GJPPK2LBPM GJPPK2LBHN" __gwt_header="header-gwt-uid-5588" __gwt_column="column-gwt-uid-5587"
            colspan="1"/>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <colgroup>
</table>
```

The table results, main body is in a separate table.  It's HTML snippet is (This is the table I am iterating through):

```
<table id="reporting_view_report_dg_main_body" cellspacing="0"
       style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 17px;">
    <colgroup>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBJM GJPPK2LBAN" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
        <td class="GJPPK2LBIM GJPPK2LBKM GJPPK2LBLM GJPPK2LBBN">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-5611" style="outline-style:none;">1</div>
        </td>
        <td class="GJPPK2LBIM GJPPK2LBKM GJPPK2LBBN">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-5612" style="outline-style:none;" tabindex="0">
                <input type="radio" name="report"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GJPPK2LBIM GJPPK2LBKM GJPPK2LBBN">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-5613" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span class="" title="43"
                      style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">43</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GJPPK2LBIM GJPPK2LBKM GJPPK2LBBN">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-5614" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span title="Matched from: Name( -word/initial match -spelling score: 86) & Address(complete address) & DOB & Phone & ACVSEQ"
                      style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">Name[wi ,(86)]Address[I]DOB[]Phone[]ACVSEQ[]</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GJPPK2LBIM GJPPK2LBKM GJPPK2LBBN">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-5615" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span class="" title="15/2/1959 00:00:00"
                      style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">15/2/1959 00:00:00</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GJPPK2LBIM GJPPK2LBKM GJPPK2LBBN">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-5616" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span class="" title="Mr.|A S|Pierre|Male"
                      style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">Mr.|A S|Pier|Male</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GJPPK2LBIM GJPPK2LBKM GJPPK2LBBN">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-5617" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span class="" title=""
                      style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GJPPK2LBIM GJPPK2LBKM GJPPK2LBBN">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-5618" style="outline-style:none;">
<span class="" title="01226 710211"
      style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GJPPK2LBIM GJPPK2LBKM GJPPK2LBBN">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-5619" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span class="" title=""
                      style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GJPPK2LBIM GJPPK2LBKM GJPPK2LBBN">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-5620" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span class="" title="WINDWHISTLE|PINNER HILL|PINNER|MIDDLESEX|HA5 3XY"
                      style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">WHISTLE|PINNER HILL|PINNER|MIDDLESEX|</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GJPPK2LBIM GJPPK2LBKM GJPPK2LBBN">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-5621" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span class="" title="07966799994|Mr."
                      style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">07966700000|Mr.</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="GJPPK2LBIM GJPPK2LBKM GJPPK2LBFN GJPPK2LBBN">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-5622" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span class="" title=""
                      style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;"/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBIN" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBJM" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="2">
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBIN" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="3">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If i use the following Xpath in Firebug Xpath checker all the rows in column 4 are highlighted.

```
//table[@id="reporting_view_report_dg_main_body"]//tr//td[4]//span
```

How can i solve this issue in my Selenium Python code iterating over the table.
There are 4 rows in the table.

Or is there an alternative way I can get all the values from column 4 into a list and then iterate over the list and check if the value "86" is not there.
By using find_elements_by_xpath

Like the following, not sure how correct this code is:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="reporting_view_report_dg_main_body"]//tr//td[4]//span')
for i in elements
    if elements.text[i] not in "86":
        return True
    else return False
```

Thanks, Riaz

Comment: I haven't tested your code but this looks weird: `if elements.text[i] not in "86":` What if you switch the terms around so it reads like this: `if "86" not in elements.text[i]:` Example: `"i am a string containing the number 86" in "86" False` but `"86" in "i am a string containing the number 86" True` I suspect you're checking if `elements.text[i]` in its entirety is equal to the strings "8", "6" or "86"

Comment: At the end of the html snippet there are 3 extra `tr` tags, without any `td` children. They are iterated also in your code - the code takes all the `td` tags from these ones too - but it can't find any. When it is trying to access the 5th element in the empty list, it dies. Try a cell number check before accessing the cell for example.